# Concat ConnectableObservables

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I have a `List` of `ConnectableObservable`, and I want to run one item from the list when the previous item is done. I've tried applying `concat()` method on the list, but apparently this method doesn't work on ConnectableObservables. How can I do this?

This is what I've tried:

```
ConnectableObservable<Long> observable1 =
    Observable.timer(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish();

ConnectableObservable<Long> observable2 =
    Observable.timer(1550, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish();


List<ConnectableObservable<Long>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(observable1);
list.add(observable2);

Observable.concat(list).doOnNext(aLong -> {
    Log.i("result", aLong.toString());
}).subscribe();

observable1.connect();
observable2.connect();
```

Here, `observable2` runs 50 milliseconds after `observable1` completes, not 1550 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't invoke `connect()` method on `ConnectableObservable`, so it hadn't started to publish anything.

Put

```java
observable1.connect();
observable2.connect();
```

at the end of your code.
Alternatively you can add `.autoConnect(1)` to your `observable1` and `observable2`.

It doesn't work simultaneously as following junit confirms it:

```java
    @Test
    void connectableTest() {
        TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        ConnectableObservable<Integer> observable1 =
                Observable
                        .just(1, 2, 3)
                        .zipWith(
                                Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler), (integer, time) -> integer)
                        .publish();
        ConnectableObservable<Integer> observable2 =
                Observable
                        .just(4, 5, 6)
                        .zipWith(
                                Observable.interval(3, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler), (integer, time) -> integer)
                        .publish();

        List<ConnectableObservable<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(observable1);
        list.add(observable2);

        TestObserver<Integer> output = Observable.concat(list).test();

        observable1.connect();
        observable2.connect();

        testScheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        output.assertValues(1,2,3,4,5,6).assertComplete();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't worked. If I just run `connect()` on the ConnectableObservables, they will all run simultaneous.

Comment: It cannot work simultaneously as concat operator is used. I updated my response with junit which confirms that.

Comment: I updated my question with a better example

Comment: Ok, I see you're using some kind of delay, but actually it doesn't change anything it this case - values are still emitted one after another (not simultaneously). Check out my updated junit.

Comment: Yeah, values are emitted one after another. But what I need is one ConnectableObservable running only after the previous one is done. I can't have they running together

Comment: Question is what do you mean that second stream is running "after the previous one is done". This is what you should have exactly in this case. When you take a closer look on concat's marble diagram, second observable starts once first observable sends complete event, so after first stream is done.

Comment: Remove the initial 3 seconds delay. They'll run together. I updated the question with a simpler example